# How will you ensure that a container 1 runs before container 2 while using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know can we set order of pods to be up and running with the help of docker compose file , Suppose we have 2 running pods for one application can we set priority that pod 2 should come up 1st  then the other pods ? If yes can i know how?